# Any nontrivial bounded map is open

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Show that any nontrivial $f \in B(X,\mathbb{K})$ is an open map.

This is a simple question, but I don't see how it is solved.
If $f$ is surjective, then we can apply the Open Mapping Thm to show that $f$ is open. But how to see that $f$ is surjective?

Comment: [More generally …](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425889/is-this-map-to-a-finite-dimensional-topological-vector-space-an-open-map)

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that “non-trivial” means that it's not the null map. But then $f(X)$ contains some non-null scalar from $\mathbb K$ and, since it must be a vector subspace of $\mathbb K$, it must be the whole $\mathbb K$.